# Continously writing terminal output to text file

Tags: files, io-redirection, text

I am running a small cli python app in terminal. It loops infinitely and outputs text to the terminal. I want to output the text to a file, and I can do that with the following command `python [my cli app] >> log.txt`, but I have to break the loop first before the file is closed and effectively saved. Is there a way to read the latest contents from the text file while the loop keeps running in the background?

SO BASICALLY:

```
~ $  [INFINITE LOOP] >> log.txt
```

then while thats running forever, I want to access `log.txt`.
At the moment, it only saves the terminal output to the file once I stop the command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I hope that explains it

Comment: I think you want `tail -f log.txt` but I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question right.

Comment: Problem is, tail only executes after you break the loop. I don't want to break the loop at all, or am I wrong? =/
And doesn't the tail command display existing text? I want to save text ^^

Comment: Why do you have to break the loop? I think what you're running into is an output buffer. You can rest assured that once enough data has been buffered to justify a `write()` that one will be made. If the loop ran infinitely and never flushed the buffer to output, it would require infinite resources to hold it until it did. So just make sure that your loop is actually generating data, then sit back and wait.

Comment: Or maybe `python something.py | tee -a log.txt`? (i.e., output to the terminal and append to log.txt at the same time)

Comment: Roughly 10 lines are added to the console every second. I'm not sure how large my buffer is but I need it to update at least once every 5 seconds if possible. I'm using the 'script' command in the meanwhile to run the loop and break it every 5 seconds to write the lines to the file.

Comment: @PSkocik - that shouldn't work any differently than the `tail` thing, anyway. In both cases the delay is rooted in the `python` out buffer - w/ `tail` you wait until it does a write to the logfile, at which point `tail` notices and copies the new data to the terminal, but with `tee` you wait until it does a write to the pipe, at which time `tee` reads it and copies it to both the log file and the terminal. At least w/ `tail` you can easily end the output to the terminal w/o needing to get creative to prevent killing `python`.

Comment: So far I can use 3 different commands that result in the contents being saved, but only after hours of running the loop. Is there a way I can flush the buffer sooner? thanks for your explanation Mike ^^ appreciate it

Comment: @JohnKahts - surely there is some `python` language primitive for adjusting the size of the output buffer? The difference between the terminal and the outfile, by the way, is a common convention that reserves resources when a process is backgrounded and expends them lavishly when foregrounded. Buffers are *good* things - writes are *expensive*. If you have an infinite loop which logs data why not just let it run in the background and conserve resources. You can *not* break the loop and still get terminal speed output like: `luit -olog mylog python >/dev.null`.

Comment: Then make it line-buffered (`stdbuf -oL python something.py`) or explicitly flush in the python script.

Comment: Thanks Mike! that worked =)

luit -olog mylog python [cli app]
What do I do now? xD Do I have to mark it as an answer?

Comment: That's not an answer. But you *could* write one. Understand, though, that you just effectively wrapped your program in its own pseudo-terminal - it's got its own byte-by-byte kernel buffer and `stty` line-editing interface and master-side monitor application and all of the other overhead which that entails.

Comment: @PSkocik Thanks for answering man =) I tried that and it still didn't want to save =/ maybe I'm just using stdbuf incorrectly. The command ran fine though, without errors.

Comment: @mikeserv It's working though haha. I'm not completely sure what all that means, but is there any reason that I shouldn't be using your method? I'm not running on very limited resources

Comment: ...said the grasshopper to the ant...

Comment: real-talk, though: go google and find out how to adjust your write buffer with python. It must be possible. just that stdbuf didn't work is a pretty clear indication that python is doing some adjustments of its own at the the start anyway. Probably when you import some kind of file module or whatever you do in python. stdbuf works by injecting a c-lib call to set the out-buffer then execs your target app - so if the target app sets its own buffer later it was all for nought.

Comment: alright, fair enough =) Thanks though =) I'll try to simplify it from here

Comment: I will google it and maybe in a month's time I will know my away around Python ^^ I'm just a tiny C# programmer fiddling around in Python xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### simulation.py:

(output 10 lines every second)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

i=0
while True:
    print("{} what up {}".format(i,i%10))
    if i%10==9:
        time.sleep(1)
    i+=1
```

In one terminal:

```
$ stdbuf -oL python simulation.py >> log.txt
```

In another one:

```
$ tail -f log.txt #10 new lines every second
```

Comment: Thanks so much ^^ this works too now. I assume this is a more effective way what the luit command? Mike said to rather adjust the buffer than to run a seperate pseudo terminal thing

Comment: @JohnKahts - this is more *efficient* because it only needs to add a littlle logic at process init time and afterwards ceases to factor altogether. That can detract from its effectiveness in some cases, but, if it *doesn't*, then it does more with less, which is always the best way to do things *(as I see it, anyway)*. By the way, I think you can get pretty specific about i/o buffer sizes with `stdbuf`, and so you might find a more conservative size which suits your needs. It would still be better though to find how to do it in your program - so you might adjust buffers dynamically to need.

Comment: @mikeserv - The amount of lines that are outputted is inconsistent, since it is dependant on the amount of queries I get from users. I understand that it would be better to incorporate the whole text file thing inside my code. So I shall try doing that as soon as I have the courage ;P
Thanks again for your help sir =)

Answer (score 0):

Working off PSkocik's answer:

instead of

```
$ stdbuf -oL python simulation.py >> log.txt
```

do

```
$ stdbuf -oL python simulation.py | tee log.txt
```

This way you'll be able to view the original output of the program as well on the same screen.