# Linux terminal output to file, but as filtered?

Tags: text-processing

Similar topic: [Continously writing terminal output to text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217484/continously-writing-terminal-output-to-text-file)

I have a usb RF receiver on ubuntu mate, which gives me this kind of data to terminal:

```
b';311;'

b';312;'

b';312;00000000;036;552;1014f49;3020;2659;6294;1049;2659;S;'

b';313;'
```

Can I save only that longest one? Preferrably without "b';xxx" but I can parse it later too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pipe your RF data into a program that can do the filtering then into a file

```
cat | ./filter.pl < /dev/ttyusb0 >> output.file
```

`filter.pl` does the, you guessed it, filtering:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

# disable buffering    
$|=1;

$re = qr/
  ^         # Match start of line
  b';       # b quote semi colon
  \d+       # Match one or more digits
  ;         # semi colon
  (.+)      # One or more characters, store the match as $1
  ;'        # semi colon, single quote
/x;

while (<>) {
  print "$1\n" if $_ =~ $re
}
```

The regular expression matches your format and pulls out the characters between the last two semi colons.

Comment: Thanks, gotta look into piping more to get the output to the input of the other program.

Comment: +1.  one nice point worth mentioning is that by pre-defining the regex with `qr/.../` it is pre-compiled, so doesn't need to be compiled on every pass through the loop.

Comment: @cas Perl knows to compile a static regex once and then reference the same program on each iteration. I use `qr` so I can keep re's separate and documented via `/x`. Using the variable could possibly be minutely slower due to the lookup.

Comment: @Thomashamka if whatever is reading your rf data doesn't do standard output then you can always go to a file and process the file with your `sed` or `perl`

Comment: @matt, perl knows how to but doesn't by default when the RE is in a variable unless you pre-compile with `qr//` or use the `/o` modifier, e.g. `m//o` or `s///o` etc.  otherwise it wouldn't be able to correctly use REs that change, e.g.  inside a loop.

Comment: I see. I was comparing `qr` to using a statically defined `if $_ =~ /re/`

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea how to use this :). Do You know any good links where I could see examples? I need to open my script first and use this or open it with this? Bit lost.

Comment: That's a bit hard without knowing the mechanism. How do you get the rf data to the terminal in the first place?  Are you accessing something in `/dev`?

Comment: @Matt, yes. I am only accessing /dev/ttyUSB0. I can read the data without the script with bash it seems. cat /dev/ttyusb0 >> output.txt reads the data, but its not real time data. First I have to open the serial port with the script and after that cat works too.

Comment: @Matt, do I need to edit this filter.pl somehow? "Store the match as $1 says in there. As I just cannot get it to work.

Comment: That code works when using `cat` and your sample data. I've modified the example to disable buffering in case you are getting caught out by that. Also included the input from your tty in the command. Try that?

Comment: @Matt You are incredible. Cat didn't work for some reason but replacing cat  with python3 -u ./script.py /dev/ttyUSB0 did the trick. One last question about the perl code. Can I edit the "Digit" part so that it doesnt matter how many digits it gives? As it seems it can run from 1 to unlimited (to an extent). Thank You so much. If You ever come to Tokyo or Helsinki,Finland, let me know and I'll treat You local food :D

Comment: Any number of digits added.  If you have a python script that is reading the device then it would probably be easier to do the filtering in the python.

Answer (score 0):

In `sed`, with basic regex:

```
whatever | sed -n "s/^b';[0-9]\{3\}];\(.\+\);'/\1/p" >> output_file
```

In `sed`, with extended regex:

```
whatever | sed -n "s/^b';[0-9]{3};(.+);'/\1/p" >> output_file
```

Comment: This seems to be a suitable too. I am bit lost with this type of thing so how do I use this? What I mean is, how do I start my script from this one? Thanks a million.

Comment: you run the program that produces the output (i don't know what it's called, so i used `whatever` above) and pipe it into the sed script.  or @Matt's perl script.  if you need more help, post a new question with your script (or an extract that exemplifies the problem) and specific question(s).

Comment: I was using it the right way, but for some reason it is not working. Will make a new post at some point if needed, but I will try to figure it out first. Thanks for super fast reply.

Comment: does your program write to stdout (e.g. the terminal), or does it write direct to a file?  if the former, you can use the pipe method as already described.  if not, you can post-process the file (after your program has finished writing to it) with `sed -e "....." inputfile.txt >> output_file`